# Render package documentation into github wiki

Tags: r, r-markdown, devtools, roxygen2

**Question:**
Are there any tricks which would render package documentation `Rd` files into github wiki pages?
github wiki pages supported markups: https://github.com/github/markup#markups

**Background:**
There are tons of CRAN packages doc on html mirrors. This kind of web-template for R documentation could be extended for github hosted packages. If `Rd` to wiki would be possible this would be very easy. Many, maybe even most of, github hosted packages do not use wiki at all.

Comment: Is there a specific programming question in here?

Comment: Question how one could use which particular function to transform `Rd` file into github wiki page. I understand it is quite an open question.

Comment: As it stands, it could be closed as off-topic (looking for a tool). I don't know what a good hub would be for such questions.

Comment: These [wikis](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Home/_edit) are just markdown. You could write vignettes for you package to follow this simple format and also call it a github wiki

Comment: Jan, you can clone the wiki locally. So you can convert Rmd to md or write directly as a md file and upload it. As a side note, perhaps adding "github" to tag makes sense?

Comment: yes, but what about `Rd` files? the core part of documentation.

Comment: Oops.. misread, sorry. Not sure if that'll be rendered properly.

Comment: Recently [Rmd was allowed to be rendered as markdown](https://github.com/github/markup/pull/343). Maybe try an FR there for Rd as well (although it's not exactly the same)?

Comment: It seems that it is totally different thing, as Rmd files are already valid markdown files which Rd are not at all. We need to process Rd into one of those: https://github.com/github/markup#markups

Comment: Well, not for wiki pages, but gh-pages could use https://github.com/hadley/staticdocs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of functions in `tools` design to work with `Rd` files.

One option would be to convert it to html and then to markdown using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/):

```
#' Convert rd file to markdown
#' @param rd path to rd file
rd_to_markdown <- function(rd) {
    html <-  paste(rd, ".html", sep = "")
    tools::Rd2HTML(tools::parse_Rd(rd), out = html)
    system( paste("pandoc -s -r html ", html, " -o ", rd, ".text", sep=""))
    unlink(html)
}
```

Result is far form pretty but it could be worse.